# Is there a way to include a directory when using CommonJS modules and require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have the following structure

```
|-src
|--test.js
|-spec
|--test_spec.js
```

I was wondering is there a way to include the src directory to the require path? I am trying to do the following in test_spec.js

```
require('test');
```

Instead of doing:

```
require('../src/test.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `src` to the `NODE_PATH` environment variable.

```
export NODE_PATH=/path/to/src
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `package.json` file you can require the directory where the file is and it will require the "main" file specified in it.

```
{
  "main": "src/text.js"
}
```